# remove file in Cron task

Tags: linux, unix, cron, debian

I have the following command line that I run on a Debian:

```
 ls -d  mypath/filename* -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +1 | xargs rm -f
```

**Result :** **OKAY** (the file is removed)

But I want to run this command periodically, and if I put this command in a Cron job, then it doesnt work (file not removed)

I checked the logs, and there are no errors nor warnings

**What I tried :**

```
 * * * * * bash -c "ls -d  mypath/filename* -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +1 | xargs rm -f"
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Probably you need to put the whole path and not a relative path in the ls command.

Comment: What is the frequency of running your script? Your entry `* * * * *` gives me impression that this means script would be running every minute(though didn't check this entry,just a thought). If you set it correct timings and check it once please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it's just for a testing purpose